# Cell Color Total Count

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm Trying to create a program to **total the amount of cells containing green and red font in column A among all the sheets in the workbook**.

In the provided code below the code it counts **ALL** the cells containing green and red font in all the cells of the worksheets.

Please be sure to leave a comment if you can guide me in the right direction!

I also made an example google sheet of what im trying to accomplish:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yLfCxaT-cIl_W77Y67xdg_ZTSQlg9X2a5vxAH4JtDpk/edit?usp=sharing

````
Sub Test_It()

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet ' Define as worksheet if you're going to loop through sheets and none is a Graph/Chart sheet

    Dim printRow As Integer ' Beware that integer it's limited to 32k rows (if you need more, use Long)
    printRow = 2


    For Each mySheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets ' use the mySheet object previously defined

        Range("N" & printRow).Value = "Sheet Name:"
        Range("O" & printRow).Value = mySheet.Name
        Range("P" & printRow).Value = "Approval:"
        Range("Q" & printRow).Value = SumGreen(mySheet) ' you can pass the sheet as an object
        Range("R" & printRow).Value = "Refused:"
        Range("S" & printRow).Value = SumRed(mySheet)
        printRow = printRow + 1
    Next mySheet

End Sub

Function SumGreen(mySheet As Worksheet) As Long ' define the type the function is going to return

    Dim myCell As Range

    Dim counter As Long

    For Each myCell In mySheet.UsedRange ' UsedRange is the range that has information

        If myCell.Font.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71) Then ' 255 is red, not green, change to whatever you need

            counter = counter + 1 ' change to counter + mycell.value if you have values and you want to sum them

        End If

    Next myCell

    ' Set the function to return the counter
    SumGreen = counter

End Function

Function SumRed(mySheet As Worksheet) As Long ' define the type the function is going to return

    Dim myCell As Range

    Dim counter As Long

    For Each myCell In mySheet.UsedRange ' UsedRange is the range that has information

        If myCell.Font.Color = 255 Then ' 255 is red, not green, change to whatever you need

            counter = counter + 1 ' change to counter + mycell.value if you have values and you want to sum them

        End If

    Next myCell

    ' Set the function to return the counter
    SumRed = counter

End Function```
````

Comment: Post your code. Not a photo of your code. We can't copy & paste a photo into VBA :)

Comment: Please, people, stop using colour to transport logic. Color is not data. It's decoration. Use conditional formatting to colour your data based on hard facts that are IN THE SPREADSHEET, not in someone's head. Then you can total by those rules, too.

Comment: Are you trying to get the sum of the values of green font, or get a count of the number of cells with green font?

Comment: I suggest you to create a new question. I can't understand what your new requirements are

Comment: Please take a look at the restated question along with the google sheet I created to provide what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cris:

Remember for next time to actually copy/paste your code in text, instead of pasting a picture.

Try this code and read the comments:

```
' If it's not going to return something, you can define this as a procedure (sub) and not a function
Sub Test_It()

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet ' Define as worksheet if you're going to loop through sheets and none is a Graph/Chart sheet

    Dim printRow As Integer ' Beware that integer it's limited to 32k rows (if you need more, use Long)
    printRow = 2


    For Each mySheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets ' use the mySheet object previously defined

        Range("N" & printRow).Value = "Sheet Name:"
        Range("O" & printRow).Value = mySheet.Name
        Range("P" & printRow).Value = "Approval:"
        Range("Q" & printRow).Value = SumGreen(mySheet) ' you can pass the sheet as an object


    Next mySheet


End Sub

Function SumGreen(mySheet As Worksheet) As Long ' define the type the function is going to return

    Dim myCell As Range

    Dim counter As Long

    For Each myCell In mySheet.UsedRange ' UsedRange is the range that has information

        If myCell.Font.Color = 255 Then ' 255 is red, not green, change to whatever you need

            counter = counter + 1 ' change to counter + mycell.value if you have values and you want to sum them

        End If

    Next myCell

    ' Set the function to return the counter
    SumGreen = counter

End Function
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, but I did have to add `printRow = printRow + 1` so that it would print all the following sheets in the workbook. Also, do you know how to change the `mySheet.UsedRange` to count column A in all the worksheets?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with this: how to change the mySheet.UsedRange to count column A in all the worksheets?. Give me an example

Comment: For example, one of my sheets has 13 green cells in row A. The function outputted 129. My theory was because it was counting all the rows with green text instead of just counting column A and that's why its 129. I will edit my original post with the updated coding.

Comment: Don't know if get you right but if you only want to loop through cells used in column A, you can use mySheet.UsedRange.Columns("A")

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm looking for it to do. Thanks, I added that into the code and now it outputs 0 for all the results. Not sure what the mix up is.